# Changing to new version RestSharp

Tags: c#, dependencies, version, restsharp

I have a C# project that generates a DLL called DUEDLL. I use RestSharp to consume API. I was using version 105.2.3, but sometimes the Chuncked Transfer-Encoding error occurs and doesn't return the full json. In version 105 it had the dependency only on RestSharp.DLL which I had to copy along with the application that used ComunicaDLL. So, I updated to version 110.2.0. In this release, I changed the framework to 4.7.2 and requested to update System.Text.Json and with that, generated several dependencies (DLLs): 
 Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces 
 System.TExt.Encodings.Web 
 System.Buffers 
 System.Memory 
 System.Numeric.Vectors 
 System.Runtime.ComplilerServices.Unsafe 
 System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions 
 System.ValueTuple 
[System.Text.Json Dependencies photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2BlV.png) [folder files photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1YnS.png) 
 Each of these dependencies is a DLL, and then I need to copy it together as an application that previously only needed RestSharp.DLL. Before it was just one file, now there are several. Is there any way to include these DLLs so that my DUEDLL already has these DLLs 'internally'? That is, not having the need to copy these new DLLs into the folder???`

Comment: Is the migration to net6/7 is an option for you? In this case you can to use single file publishing for the app. For the old net framework there is no such options out-of-the-box.

Comment: A simple setup copying the needed files hurts?